# Mapbox GL js 3D elevation profile

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am converting my website from Mapbox.js to Mapbox GL js. 
On the old version, I use this excellent example for a "3D" elevation profile:

[image: Mapbox.js Elevation Profile]
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/dc-bikeshare-revisited/

Now, for Mapbox GL js the map rotation and pitching is easy. Not so for the vertical elevation bars. My only idea so far is to add markers styled somehow with CSS as vertical bars. These will then be of course added to the WebGL engine from Mapbox GL js as sprites and remain client-faced even when the map is pitched and rotated. Would this work?
I don't want to lose this excellent 3D feature. Any other ideas how this can be achieved without writing a mapbox GL js plugin to access/modify the scene objects directly?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this or tried the one you proposed?

Comment: No, I have postponed this project for now.